# How can I add Apex page message when using future calls

Tags: future

I have the following code:

```
@future(callout=true)
public void methodABC(){
CalloutClass.calloutmethod();
}
```

The check for error is done in the calloutmethod.If callout has failed then apex page message is added.However this doesn't work with future calls it seems as I am getting the error: ApexPages.addMessage can only be called from a visualforce page.

Comment: The short answer is that it's not possible. If you want the callout to happen async, you could use a class that implements the queueable interface and use the job id to poll for completion.

Comment: Just call it synchronously.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I have addressed this with standard detail pages/standard controllers/triggers

1. Use a custom picklist field on the object `Callout_Status__c` with values {`Pending`, `Completed`, `Error`
2. Use another custom field on the object `Callout_Error__c` (type Text)
3. Both fields are optionally not shown on the page layout
4. Use a custom image formula field that displays, when `Callout_Status__c = Pending` a friendly message in green `"Callout in progress, wait a few seconds and refresh the page"` Use similar messages for Completed and Error (green/red, resp.) The error use case can include the error message.
5. Before the future call is made, update the object field `Callout Status__c` to `Pending`. Thus, when the page is refreshed, after the Save, the image formula displays
6. The future class, upon completion of the callout updates the object to either `Callout_status__c = Completed` or `Callout_Status__c = Error`. In the latter case, the field `Callout_Error__c` is set to the callout's error

Although future classes aren't guaranteed to run right away, they tend to run pretty quickly after being invoked so a few seconds wait for the user